# jQuery: Can you make an element stick onScroll WITHOUT using css position:fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

Or can someone tell me another way to do this (without using a plugin please)

I have a side nav on the left and some content to the right. Both elements are floated left.

I want the side nav to 'stick' when it gets to 125px from the top of the window, once scrolled down the page.

I feel like I'm close, but I'm definitely not there yet! With the code I have written, the side-nav 'jumps' up to the top of the window once we scroll to the correct window position and then it's going back to the position where I want it to 'stick'.

The other issue, is that once the .stick class is applied, the element is taken out of the document flow (because I'm applying a position: fixed;) and the .content moves over to the left to take it's place.

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/MandyMadeThis/pen/DLtsJ

** NOTE: It seems I can't recreate the side-nav 'jumping' to the top of the window on scroll, so I don't what that's all about, but I'd still like to know the correct way to do this without the content moving over to the left.**

If anyone can guide me in the right direction, that would be wonderful. Thank you.

Here is my markdown:

```
<body>
 <nav>navigation content</nav>
 <header>header content</header>
 <div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="side-nav">THIS IS THE THING I WANT TO STICK</div>  
  <div class="content">This needs to stay to the right of the .side-nav</div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.side-nav {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -17px;
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.content {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.stick {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  margin-top: 125px;
}
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
var sn = $(".side-nav");
var pos = sn.position();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowPos >= pos.top - 125) {
        sn.addClass("stick");
    } else {
        sn.removeClass("stick");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you simply need to add a `margin-left` to `.content` and remove `float`. This way the position of the content does not rely on the nav being there.

```
.content {
   width: 70%;
   margin-left: 25%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbCix

Comment: OH MAN! I knew it was something very simple that I just wasn't seeing! Thank you